# Military aid Israel has received from the US

Tags: united-states, israel, foreign-aid

How much is the sum of  military aid and economic assistance Israel has received from the United States,  since it declared till now?

Comment: US aid for Israel is very heavily discussed by critics of Israel. If any country’s aid from the US has readily accessible information on the internet, it would be Israel. What research have you done before asking this question?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Jewish Virtual Library](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/total-u-s-foreign-aid-to-israel-1949-present) $79,823.4 million in military aid and $129,808.527 million in total aid (click the link for a per-year overview)

To put that into relation, in [2017](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/world/which-countries-get-the-most-foreign-aid/) for example US security assistance consisted of:

- Afghanistan: 3.67 billion
- Israel: 3.1 billion
- Egypt: 1.31 billion
- Iraq: $808 million
- Jordan: 367.6 million
- Pakistan: 319,7 million
- Syria: 313.5 million
- Colombia: 203,9 million
- Lebanon: 123,5 million
- Mexico: 85,6 million

For an overview of economic aid visit the link (Israel isn't in the top 10 there, and hasn't received any non-military aid worth mentioning since 2007).

Comment: while this answer has good data, the question is not to compare   US  assistance to  israel with other countries in  2017, the question is: How much is *the sum of* military aid and economic assistance Israel has received from the United States, **since it declared till now**?

Comment: @user1 Right, I answered that in the first sentence. But I also think that the number is mostly meaningless if you have no point of comparison on how much that actually is. I chose 2017 - the data looks similar in other years. I think a complete overview over all US foreign aid would have been better, but I wasn't able to find that (if you do, please feel free to post an answer).

Comment: "I chose 2017 - the data looks similar in other years." is not true; e.g. Afghanistan case. does Afghanistan receive such a assistance  for 70 years?

Comment: @user1 Sorry, yes, I meant in recent years. Though as you can see from the linked overview, military aid to Israel didn't start until '59, and didn't really take off until '71.